# How to migrate the following query from informix to oracle where query has the outer

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration, informix

The following query  in informix which has outer:

```
SELECT   T1.matter,T1.test test,T1.pkg pkg,T1.grade grade,
   T2.name  name ,T4.quarter quarter,SUM(T3.actual) actual, 
   SUM(T5.open) open  FROM dimen T1, customer T2, ship T3, 
timer T4, Outer facture T5, order T6, sales T7
WHERE  T3.t_date = T4.day
AND T5.date_lock = T4.day_lock 
AND T3.part_lock = T1.part_lock
AND T5.part_lock = T1.part_lock
AND T3.part_lock = T7.part_lock
AND T5.part_lock = T7.part_lock
AND T3.sold_lock= T2.cust_lock
AND T5.sold_lock = T2.cust_lock
AND T3.order_lock=T6.order_lock
AND T5.order_lock=T6.order_lock
AND T5.item LIKE '%AM%'
AND T5.open_qty=' '
AND T1.mtrl_grp IN ('SPT','TEN','PIN','TCS','JEN','SDP','TDP')
AND T3.sales_type in ('ZXR','ZDS','ZUT')
AND T4.day_lock BETWEEN start_lock AND end_lock
Group by T1.matter,T1.test,T1.pkg,T1.grade,T2.name,T4.quarter
```

Can anybody suggest how to convert it to oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as you're going to get:

```
SELECT T1.matter, T1.test test, T1.pkg pkg, T1.grade grade,
       T2.name name, T4.quarter quarter, SUM(T3.actual) actual, 
       SUM(T5.open) open 
  FROM dimen T1
  JOIN customer T2 ON T3.sold_lock= T2.cust_lock
  JOIN ship T3 ON T3.part_lock = T1.part_lock
  JOIN timer T4 ON T3.t_date = T4.day
  LEFT OUTER JOIN facture T5
    ON T5.date_lock = T4.day_lock
   AND T5.part_lock = T1.part_lock
   AND T5.sold_lock = T2.cust_lock
  JOIN order T6
    ON T3.order_lock = T6.order_lock
   AND T5.order_lock = T6.order_lock
  JOIN sales T7
    ON T3.part_lock = T7.part_lock
   AND T5.part_lock = T7.part_lock
 WHERE T5.item LIKE '%AM%'
   AND T5.open_qty = ' '
   AND T1.mtrl_grp IN ('SPT', 'TEN', 'PIN', 'TCS', 'JEN', 'SDP', 'TDP')
   AND T3.sales_type in ('ZXR', 'ZDS', 'ZUT')
   AND T4.day_lock BETWEEN start_lock AND end_lock
 GROUP BY T1.matter, T1.test, T1.pkg, T1.grade, T2.name, T4.quarter
```

In theory, there could be some differences between the result you get with this query and the result you get with the original.  You should try this revised query against your data in your Informix database to check whether it is doing as you want/expect.

I'm not entirely happy with all the join conditions referencing columns in T5, the outer-joined table.